# Compile Error with Web Assembly in Web App?

Tags: web, webassembly

I am getting the following error when I am using a Web Assembly library in my application.

“CompileError: WebAssembly.compile(): expected 6796709 bytes, fell off end @+11”

Any idea on what could be going wrong. Also what does this error mean.

Thanks for the help in advance!